# Firebase NSDictionary to Textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i place my firebase data into a Textview? The information coming in is as a NSDictionary.

```
2016-05-24 10:15:45.523 Weather[1248:29689] {
baro = 1;
humidity = 3;
temp = 2;
}
```

I have tried to convert to string then to textview, but that doesn't work?

```
    Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath: @"id/"];

[usersRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.key, snapshot.value);


    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);

    string1 = snapshot.value;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so whats is you problem, u need string ? u need testView ?

Comment: i want to place all the information into a textview from there i know what to do.

Comment: `[snapshot.value objectForKey:@"Your Key"];` try this once..add it to textview.text....hope this works

Comment: No tried it no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:snapshot.value];
NSString *stri=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict];
```

i got result something like this on textview
[image]

This may not be exactly what you want but, This will help you get started.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does grab the data to the textview without any problems. Yes from here i can at least make a start. Thank you